# conversion from pair to Vector2f causing out of range errors

Tags: c++, vector

I am working on an implementation of maze generation using Kruskal's Algorithm. I have done everything except the last step, which is converting my vector of pairs of floats (vector>) into a vector of Vector2f (vector). Here's the function I use to do this:

```
void ConvertToVector2F(vector<std::pair<float, float>> verts, vector<Vector2f> verts2f)
{
    //convert verts vector of pairs to vector of vector2f (MS stuff)

    for (int i = 0; i < verts.size(); i++)
    {
        Vector2f newVert = { verts[i].first, verts[i].second };
        verts2f.push_back(newVert);
    }
}
```

This is called from the main function, and after conversion, the vector of Vector2f objects is returned from the main function. When I return verts2f from main, it causes a series of errors:

> "Unhandled exception at 0x76EFC42D in Lab1.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0025EDF8."
>
> "Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved
>   across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a
>   function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer
>   declared with a different calling convention."
>
> "Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved
>   across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a
>   function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer
>   declared with a different calling convention."

These do not cause the entire function to crash, but the maze generation does not work.

When I pass a generic vector of vector2fs, such as `{ {0,0} }`, the errors do not occur.

I suspect that this is a problem with how I'm handling the vector object, especially because the errors I mentioned all mention something about an

std::vector< float,std::allocator >* object.

I do not not really know what to do to fix the problem. I only have a sense of what is causing the issue.

Can anyone shed light on this problem? I'm writing in Visual Studio 2013 on a Windows 7 x64 machine.

Comment: `verts2f` is being passed by value, so you're only adding the vertices to the local copy. Can you show the code that calls this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform *pass by reference* to get the modified `verts2f` inside `main`

```
void ConvertToVector2F(vector<std::pair<float, float>> verts, 
                       vector<Vector2f> &verts2f);
```

Also this is the desired way as it will avoid the expensive copy into parameters. And this will be even better:

```
void ConvertToVector2F(vector<std::pair<float, float>> &verts, 
                       vector<Vector2f> &verts2f);
```

Now only the starting address of two vectors are passed as parameters.

Comment: I came back to this question to say that I found the same problem on my own, but looks like you and others beat me to it. I am off to solve the new problems that this has brought up. Thank you to all who replied.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the function as

```
void ConvertToVector2F(vector<std::pair<float, float>> verts, 
                       vector<Vector2f> &verts2f);
```

That is declare the second parameter as a reference to the vector.

As for me then I would declare the function as

```
void ConvertToVector2F( const vector<std::pair<float, float>> &verts, 
                       vector<Vector2f> &verts2f);
```

Comment: +1 and Sorry Sir, unconsciously my answer became almost same as yours specially after I edited. I would appreciate if your answer will be accepted as you were first!

Comment: @Kaidul Islam There is nothing wonderful that answers sometimes coincide.:)

Comment: I appreciate such acts of humility, but I found the extra bit of explanatory text in Kaidul's answer to be that much more helpful, no offense intended toward you, Vlad. I appreciate both of you for helping me out with this problem.